# Поправить запрос sql

Tags: sql

Есть такой запрос:
`SELECT c.category_id as 'category_id', c2.category_id as 'check_inner' FROM oc_category c LEFT JOIN oc_category c2 ON(c.category_id = c2.parent_id) WHERE c.parent_id = '59' AND c.status = 1`

Он возвращает следующее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как составить запрос так чтобы он возвращал следующее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Т.е. нужны только уникальные поля category_id, check_inner служит только для проверки, если NULL то одно, если не NULL то другое?

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT c.category_id ...` ?

Comment: Не работает, возвращает то что на 1 скрине

Comment: Группировка по первому столбцу, min по второму. Подходит?

Comment: А как это будет выглядеть в запросе, хотя бы примерно?

Comment: Написал в ответе.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT
  c.category_id AS category_id,
  MIN(c2.category_id) AS check_inner
FROM oc_category c
LEFT JOIN oc_category c2
  ON (c.category_id = c2.parent_id)
WHERE c.parent_id = '59'
AND c.status = 1
GROUP BY c.category_id;
```

Comment: Хм.. работает, нужно почитать об операторе group by, спасибо.

Comment: www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_getting_summarizing_values.html